# Isomorphism types of simple $KG$-modules with $G=S_3$

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

I am trying an exercises on determining all isomorphism types of simple $KG$-modules with $G=S_3$, the symmetric group of degree $3$.

If $K$ is algebraically closed then we can use the following result :

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $V$ a simple $KG$-module and
>   $A$ an abelian subgroup of $G$, then
>
> $$\dim_kV\leq |G:A|$$

Hence, if $K$ is algebraically closed, we can apply this result for $A=<(12)>$ and obtain that $dim_k(V)\leq 3$, which implies that there are $3$ different isomorphism types of simple $KG$-modules.

In case, $K$ is not algebraically closed, then we can not apply the result above. Could you give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in the case of fields with positive characteristic or not? The characteristic 0 case is typically easier.

Comment: I think I should also consider the case when char K is positive.

Comment: I don't see why you think $\dim_K(V)\leq 3$ would mean there are only three isoclasses of $K[G]$ modules. If $G$ were a direct sum of $5$ groups of order 2, and $N$ were a subgroup of index 2, then over $\Bbb C$ your result says that $\dim_{\Bbb C}V\leq 2$, but $K[G]\cong \oplus_{i=1}^5\Bbb C$ has five isoclasses of simple modules.

Comment: $G$ also has an abelian subgroup $A=\langle (123)\rangle$ of index two implying the inequality $\dim_k V\le 2$. The number of non-isomorphic simple modules is still three, because there are two non-isomorphic one-dimensional modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some notes on what you could do. I might write $R$ for $K[S_3]$ at times.

There should be three cases: $char(K)=2$, $char(K)=3$ and "otherwise".

Overarching everything here is the basic fact that the isoclasses of simple modules for a semisimple ring are known once you have factored it into simple rings. If $R=\oplus R_i$ is a factorization of a semisimple ring into simple rings, then all simple left $R$ modules look like $\oplus I_i$ where each $I_i$ is a left ideal of $R_i$, exactly one of them is nonzero, and the one that is nonzero is a minimal left ideal of its ring.

---

In the "otherwise" case, the group ring will be semisimple by [Maschke's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem), and you can go about trying to deduce what it looks like. Let $N$ be the rotations in $S_3$. Since $K[S_3]$ is semisimple, we know that the kernel of the projection to $K[S_3/N]$ is a summand of $R$ (two dimensional) and that its kernel $\omega(N)$ is another summand ring of dimension four over $K$. The factor rings are also semisimple.

Now considering dimensions and the Artin-Wedderburn structure of $R$, the commutative ring $K[S_3/N]$ could in theory be a two dimensional field extension of $K$, or else it is just $K\oplus K$. The former case is ruled out when you notice that $\frac{1}{2}(1+\tau)$ is a nontrivial idempotent in this ring, and so it cannot be a field. ($\tau$ is the reflection in $S_3$.) Already here you can see there are at least three nonisomorphic simple modules for $R$.

The kernel $\omega(N)$ is four dimensional over $K$, and so in principal it could be a $2\times 2$ matrix ring over $K$, or else some mixture of $K$ and two degree extensions over $K$. It cannot just be $K\oplus K\oplus K\oplus K$ because that would make $R$ commutative.

If $K$ happened to be algebraically closed, then the extensions are ruled out, and it would have to be the matrix ring. That would mean there are *exactly* three isoclasses of simple $R$ modules.

---

In the other two cases, things would be similar except $rad(R)$ is nonzero. We would make use of the fact that $R$ and $R/rad(R)$ have the same simple modules, and that $R/rad(R)$ is again a semisimple ring.  Things would be a bit easier to deduce because of the lower dimension.